# Multiple selects are not being submitted in the form using post?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a form where I need to allow user to select different values (from select tag) against some labels. 
I have two different array in php.

1. the standard array that contains the labels for select.
2. a set of values to be selected against the labels.

My problem is when I press the submit button, the form is submitted but `$_POST` does not show any value selected by the select tag. I want to get the selected values against the labels.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $data = array ('name', 'phone', 'address');
    $values = array('a','2344','xyz');
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  ?>" method="post">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){ ?>
          <label for='<?php $data[$i]?>'> <?php echo $data[$i]?></label>  
          <select name='<?php $data[$i]?>' id = '<?php $data[$i]?>'> 
         <?php foreach($values as $val){ ?>        
             <option value='<?php $val ?>'>  <?php echo $val ?> </option>
         <?php } ?>    

        </select>   
   <?php  } ?>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>    
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo$_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

When I press the submit button the error I get is "Notice: Undefined index: name". I have extensively searched in the questions already posted about multiple select statements but none of the answers matched my criteria. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need to place an echo statement before every value you need to print in HTML. as you did in this statement [<?php echo $val ?>]. Just place an echo for every statement of this kind in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgot to print variables

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  ?>" method="post">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){ ?>
          <label for='<?php echo $data[$i]?>'> <?php echo $data[$i]?></label>  
          <select name='<?php echo $data[$i]?>' id = '<?php echo $data[$i]?>'> 
         <?php foreach($values as $val){ ?>        
             <option value='<?php echo $val ?>'>  <?php echo $val ?> </option>
         <?php } ?>    

        </select>   
   <?php  } ?>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>    
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo$_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not written echo before each variable in selectbox:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];  ?>" method="post">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) { ?>
               <label for='<?php echo $data[$i]; ?>'> <?php echo $data[$i]?></label>  
               <select name='<?php echo $data[$i]; ?>' id = '<?php echo $data[$i]; ?>'> 
                    <?php foreach($values as $val){ ?>        
                        <option value='<?php echo $val; ?>'>  <?php echo $val ?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>    
                </select>   
        <?php  } ?>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>  
    </form>
```